# Make the same thing made with docker-compose on k8s

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose

Is there a way to run the docker-compose app identically on k8s?

Currently the content of my docker-compose.yml file is as follows:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  registry:
    restart: always
    image: registry:2
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    environment:
      REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE: /certs/domain.crt
      REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY: /certs/domain.key
      REGISTRY_AUTH: htpasswd
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH: /auth/htpasswd
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM: Registry Realm
    volumes:
      - /home/app/docker/test/data:/var/lib/registry
      - /home/app/docker/test/certs:/certs
      - /home/app/docker/test/auth:/auth
  nginx:
    container_name: "nginx"
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    depends_on:
      - node
  node:
    container_name: "node"
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/index.html:/usr/src/node/index.html
    expose:
      - "3000"
```

Can you change this to work with k8s?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) You should not just request a ready solution. SO is for helping solve specific errors, after you've shown your effort solving them

Comment: Kubernetes can't build images or access local files, so in some form you will have to address the `build:` and `volumes:` blocks.  You've gotten a couple of pointers to Kompose already, but the examples of it I've seen require enough tweaking that you'll need to learn core Kubernetes concepts to make its output functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Kompose([github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose))

```
kompose convert -f docker-compose.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's an easy way to do that, but I heard about a tool called [Kompose](https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose) that might help you (I never tried it)